# Did iOS 7.1 break content-available (aka silent) push notifications for non-newsstand apps?

Tags: ios

Our app is not a newsstand content app, but does have a need to receive silent push notifications so that it can update content. In iOS 7.0 we were sending content-available notifications and those were coming through fine, even without the need for sound : "", alert : "" hacks.

As of iOS 7.1, content-available notifications are no longer delivered.

Background modes: `fetch, location`

Notification types registered: `UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert`

If I register for UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability notifications, content-available start getting delivered. However this presents a confusing alert to the user and, I'm guessing, would get the app rejected.

If I use the remote-notification background mode, the content-available notifications still aren't delivered.

I've filed a bug with Apple (rdar://16380367) but haven't gotten a response yet.

So my questions:

- Has anyone else noticed this difference in iOS 7.1?
- Is it even possible to receive content-available notifications without using the newsstand-content background mode and/or registering for UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that yes, iOS 7.1 did break content-available notifications for apps without using the newsstand-content background mode, although I haven't received anything back from Apple re: rdar://16380367 . Using the remote-notification doesn't seem to make a difference.

We worked around this by additionally sending a blank alert:

```
aps =     {
    alert = "";
    "content-available" = 1;
};
```

Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `remote-notification` to your background modes.